# Stack Overflow downgraded

Tags: discussion

Stack Overflow seems to been downgraded.

You now do not see "New" questions only "Interesting"
These only show the title (plus a lot of irrelevant crap) rather than the first few lines of the question. 
[image]
This means you need to open the link to see it is rubbish!

Is there any option to retain the current format, or do we have to suffer the Micro$oft like "upgrade"?

The new format devotes LESS space to the questions rather than the surrounds.

Answer (score 4):

The left nav will be coming to all sites, including this one, over the coming weeks, as discussed in [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309349/336144) which has been featured on the sidebar for a few weeks. It'll probably be July or beyond before it comes to RPi... but it will eventually.

The interesting sort hasn't changed. Stack Overflow has used the 'interesting' sort for years, because the 'new' sort is just too noisy to be any use. On other sites, the sorting order will remain as it is (you can see [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as an example of a site that doesn't have the 'interesting' sort but does have the redesign).

I'm guessing you use [the /questions page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions), which gives you a preview of the post's first few lines. That [still exists in the redesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions); you just click 'Questions' in the left bar instead of the top instead.

When the upgrade does finally come, you won't be able to retain the existing format, but you can hide the left navigation with a profile setting. It would then look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG4Ft.png). That does make it harder to get to the /questions page though, so probably wouldn't be very convenient for your workflow.

Comment: I still stand by downgrade. The new design wastes just as much space on top - it just has replaced the useful links with white space; now to use the site you need more waste space on the left! For extra waste there now seems to be white space on the right

Answer (score 3):

This is sort of off-topic here, but anyway...

[image]

Notice in the left nav bar it shows the "Stack Overflow" tab selected, which is https://stackoverflow.com/questions.  If I select "Home" up top instead (which is https://stackoverflow.com), I get a view more like what you are talking about, no right side nav bar, only question titles.

Comment: Mine looks nothing like the above! I opened from the Site Menu on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You need to click the 'Stack Overflow' button as goldilocks says, @Milliways. That's the equivalent of what the 'Questions' button did when it was at the top of the page. It's always been this way; the home page does **not** show previews of the question body, and it never has. The /questions page does.